# I always get the last value of an arraylist of objects

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I want to print all the items of an arrayList of objects. But it only prints the last item's values only. 
Here is my code:

```
List<items> boxes = new ArrayList<items>();
boxes.add(new items("1", 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.1f));
boxes.add(new items("2", 0.1f, 0.4f, 0.1f));
boxes.add(new items("3", 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.2f));
boxes.add(new items("4", 0.1f,0.1f, 0.3f));
boxes.add(new items("5", 0.2f, 0.1f, 0.1f));
boxes.add(new items("6", 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f));
boxes.add(new items("7", 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.1f));
boxes.add(new items("8", 0.1f, 0.3f, 0.1f));
boxes.add(new items("9", 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f));

for (items box: boxes){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("length:  " +box.dimension.get("length"));
    System.out.println("breadth:  " +box.dimension.get("breadth"));
    System.out.println("height:  " +box.dimension.get("height"));
}
```

this is the items class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class items {

    String boxNumber;
    public static Map<String, Float> dimension = new HashMap<String, Float>();
    public double volume;

    public items(float l, float b, float h) {
        volume = l * b * h;
        dimension.put("length", l);
        dimension.put("breadth", b);
        dimension.put("height", h);

    }

    public items(String boxName, float i, float j, float k) {
        boxNumber = boxName;
        volume = i * j * k;
        dimension.put("length", i);
        dimension.put("breadth", j);
        dimension.put("height", k);

    }

    public static Map<String, Float> getDimension() {
        return dimension;
    }

    public static void setDimension(Map<String, Float> dimension) {
        items.dimension = dimension;
    }

    public items rotateBox() {

        Set<String> keySet = this.dimension.keySet();
        String[] sides = keySet.toArray(new String[3]);
        dimension.put(sides[1],
                dimension.put(sides[2], dimension.get(sides[1])));
        dimension.put(sides[0],
                dimension.put(sides[2], dimension.get(sides[0])));

        return this;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dimension.get("length") * dimension.get("breadth")
                * dimension.get("height");
    }
}
```

And this is what I always get:

```
length:  0.2
breadth:  0.2
height:  0.2

length:  0.2
breadth:  0.2
height:  0.2

length:  0.2
breadth:  0.2
height:  0.2

length:  0.2
breadth:  0.2
height:  0.2

length:  0.2
breadth:  0.2
height:  0.2

length:  0.2
breadth:  0.2
height:  0.2

length:  0.2
breadth:  0.2
height:  0.2

length:  0.2
breadth:  0.2
height:  0.2

length:  0.2
breadth:  0.2
height:  0.2
```

Can anyone please tell what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't use `static` unless you want all instances to share the same values.

Comment: Don't use a map when you should be using a normal object with fields.  This performs badly, and is error prone.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `dimension` as a static variable, [which means it will be shared by all instances of your `items` class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/413898/1743880).

```
public static Map<String, Float> dimension = new HashMap<String, Float>();
```

As such, every time you create a new instance, the values in the map are overwritten by

```
dimension.put("length", l);
dimension.put("breadth", b);
dimension.put("height", h);
```

so the final values you will get are the values of the last item you inserted.

You should instead make it an instance variable with:

```
public Map<String, Float> dimension = new HashMap<String, Float>();
```

---

As a side-note:

- You should prefer `private` instance variable over public ones, and have getter.
- Consider respecting the Java naming conventions: the `items` class should be `Items`.

Answer (score 0):

You have made HashMap dimension as a static variable so it will retain its value and is shared by all the instances of items class.
Make the Map as the member variable by declaring it as

```
    public Map<String,Float> dimension = new HashMap<String,Float>();
```

This member variable will be specific to every instance of the Class items and can be accessed from constructor using "this"keyword. For example:-

```
    public items(String boxName, float i, float j, float k) {
        boxNumber = boxName;
        volume = i * j * k;
        this.dimension.put("length", i);
        this.dimension.put("breadth", j);
        this.dimension.put("height", k);
    }
```